# Puppeteer wait for page to fully load before proceeding

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Here's my code. So basically I have an element in the page that I will click. Im not sure if waitForNavigation is the correct function to use here but I want the page to load fully before proceeding on to the next step.

I could use waitForSelector as a workaround, but what if I dont have a fixed selector that I can search?

```
    await Promise.all([
      this.page.waitForNavigation(),
      element.click()
    ])
```

Comment: Try `await page.goto(url,  { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });`

Comment: But I dont use a URL, there's like a button or a link I have to click on my page that opens a new url.

Answer (score 1):

Use `options.waitUntil` ([doc](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions))

```js
await Promise.all([
  this.page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' }),
  element.click()
])
```

Comment: Doesn't work as well, ive tried every option in waitUntil

Comment: @Octane without sharing the page you're scraping and your full code, the best anyone can do is guess. Can you provide a [mcve] that can be run to illustrate "not working"? Thanks.

Comment: @Octane. A tip: to debug this kind of behavior, run your script with the V8 debugger active `node --inspect-brk` and pass the `headless: false` option to puppeteer. Then, you can make your way to your problem, try out things in the V8 REPL and put `debugger` statements where needed.